# any lodash functions for removing array that is matching from main array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, lodash

I have two array **available**, **selected** which is having some values. I am having another array named **finalAvailable** in which I want all those from the **available** array at the same time also to remove those which are present in **selected** array. An example is shown below

```
var available = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
var selected = ["B", "C"];
```

so the **finalAvailable** array will be like

```
var finalAvailable = ["A", "D", "E"];
```

I have written a code for achieving this and its working fine, but the problem is since I am using Lo-dash within my project my team lead ask whether there is any function available to achieve this using Lo-dash, I searched but could find anything, I don't know whether I am missing anything.

Can anyone tell me whether there is anything similar available in Lodash

My code is as given below

```
var available = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
var selected = ["B", "C"];

var finalAvailable = [];

for (var i = 0; i < available.length; i++) {
    var flag = true;
    for (var j = 0; j < selected.length; j++) {
        if (available[i] == selected[j]) {
            flag = false;
        }
    }
    if (flag) {
        finalAvailable.push(available[i])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```js
var available = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
var selected = ["B", "C"];

var finalAvailable = _.filter(available, function (el) {
  return _.indexOf(selected, el) === -1    
});

console.log(finalAvailable);

// or you can use _.difference
console.log(_.difference(available, selected));
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/lodash/lodash/3.0.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try without Lodash:**

```
let available = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
let selected = ["B", "C"];

let finalAvailable = available.filter(item => selected.indexOf(item) === -1);
console.log(finalAvailable);
```